# metric and Volume of spheres

Tags: geometry

Given an metric on $S^n$ (a unit sphere of dimension $n$), one can compute its volume by integrating the square root of the determinant of the metric. Is it possible to find another metric that gives a *different* volume of $S^n$? Moreover does the answer depend on $n$? An explicit example would be useful.

Comment: For any (oriented) metric $g$, $\det (\lambda^2 g) = \lambda^{2n} \det g$, so $\operatorname{vol}_{\lambda^2 g} = \lambda^n \operatorname{vol}_g$.

Comment: thats fine! What I meant by different metric was a metric in a different coordinate system. When you rescale by $\lambda$ you simply rescale the coordinates. But then you should also rescale the ranges accordingly such that you cover $X$. If you do all this correctly you get back the same volume.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. If one fixes a metric, the volume computed using some atlas of coordinate charts is independent of the choice of charts, as it has to be. But scaling the metric itself is a separate operation from changing the coordinates (by scaling or any other transformation).